# Voyager dropdown relationship ajax call

Tags: ajax, laravel, relationship, dropdown, voyager

How i can override model query which populate a belongsto relationship dropdown via ajax call.
Tha call is like http://santinisacri.local/admin/santini-soggetti/relation?type=santini_soggetti_hasone_santini_soggetti_relationship&method=add&page=1 and the response is a JSON.
I want to add a where clausole.
I have tried in model but nothing. I need to create a new controller?

Comment: Did you use `tcg/voyager`?

Comment: yes i did, v1.4

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by a overriding controller and return an array like:

```
$results['results'] = $soggetti;
return $results;
```